# Pause and resume jquery animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vBt5E/

I want to pause and unpause an endlessly scrolling jquery animation on hover, without any weird jumps.

html like this:

```
<div id="vertical-carousel">
    <div class="imagecolumn">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/120" width="200" height="120"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/100" width="200" height="100"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/80" width="200" height="90"></a>
    </div>
</div>
​
```

javascript like so:

```
var imageColumn = $('.imagecolumn');

origColumnHeight = imageColumn.height();

$(document).ready(function() {

    var columnDupe = imageColumn.contents()
                                .clone()
                                .addClass('dupe')
                                .appendTo(imageColumn);

    function scrollColumn() {
        imageColumn.css({'top': '0'})
                   .animate({top: -origColumnHeight},15000, 'linear', scrollColumn);

    }

    scrollColumn();
});
```

I know this has been asked in different form before but the various answers aren't working for me. I looked at [Tobia Conferto's "Pause" plugin](http://tobia.github.com/Pause/) and just couldn't get it to work. Ditto [this one](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Pause-Resume-animation), which is supposedly even buggier.

Please post a working fiddle if you can, it really helps. Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: @Brad It's in the second sentence...

Comment: I know what you want to do... that part is clear.  I'm asking what problem you are having.  All you've said is "just couldn't get it to work", which doesn't tell us much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the "Pause" plugin, you can get it working by doing the following:

```
$(".imagecolumn").hover(function() {
  $(this).pause();
}, function() {
  $(this).resume();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/vBt5E/1/

Make sure you include the plugin on your page! https://raw.github.com/tobia/Pause/master/jquery.pause.min.js

<sub>P.S. I prefer [PlaceDog](http://placedog.com).</sub>

Comment: Thanks Charlie. I swear this is *exactly* what I tried at one point. 7pm Friday, time to take a break I guess!